# UIActivityIndicator Disappear Before Image Loaded in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiactivityindicatorview, activity-indicator

I have a code like this

```
startAnimating(CGSize(width: 100, height: 100), message: "Loading...", type: NVActivityIndicatorType.pacman, displayTimeThreshold: 5, minimumDisplayTime: 5)
    self.view.makeToastActivity(.center)
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {            
        //self.view.addSubview(collectionNews)
        //activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
         DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.myGroup.enter()
            self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            self.view.window?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            self.getJsonFromUrl()
            self.collectionNews.dataSource = self
            self.collectionNews.delegate = self
            self.collectionNews.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5)
            self.getJsonFromUrl2()
            self.myGroup.leave()
            self.refresh_now()
            self.myGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
                self.stopAnimating()
                self.view.hideToastActivity()
                self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                self.view.window?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            }
        }            
    }
```

However, when I run the application, the activity indicator always disappear before all of the images loaded successfully. This will trigger an error when the user tries to scroll every where on the app, before all of the content loaded successfully.

even, I use 2 activity indicator, and both of them always disappear before every thing loaded.

Could anyone give me advice, which one I did wrong?

Comment: where u are showing images in tableView ?where did u put this code?can u make ur question more understandable?

Comment: u can add time for activity indicator @christ2702

Answer (score -1):

You are loading the content in the main thread. You can load/Get data from server in the background and update your UI in the main thread. Like:

```
startAnimating(CGSize(width: 100, height: 100), message: "Loading...", type: NVActivityIndicatorType.pacman, displayTimeThreshold: 5, minimumDisplayTime: 5)
    self.view.makeToastActivity(.center)
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {            
        //self.view.addSubview(collectionNews)
        //activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()

            self.myGroup.enter()
            self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            self.view.window?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            self.getJsonFromUrl()
            self.collectionNews.dataSource = self
            self.collectionNews.delegate = self
            self.collectionNews.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5)
            self.getJsonFromUrl2()
            self.myGroup.leave()
            self.refresh_now()

       DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.myGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
                self.stopAnimating()
                self.view.hideToastActivity()
                self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                self.view.window?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            }
        }            
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but it give no different result. please help me

Comment: @christ2702, can you please debug and check. Other than this method anywhere else are you hiding the loader. check is there any method getting called along with this method.